# leaves space at the bottom on chrome

Tags: jquery, css, transform

This is a responsive design and ***transform: translateY(2000px);*** has been applied on the blocks at the bottom. The animation is working fine in Chrome, but the animation seems to leave a blank space at  the bottom of the page. This happens only in Chrome.

Project Link:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/Call/
```

CSS:

```
.come-in {
  transform: translateY(2000px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}

.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s; /* So they look staggered */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s; 
}
```

JS:

```
 (function($) {

      $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

      };

    })(jQuery);

    $(window).scroll(function(d){

       $(".unWcalls").each(function(i, el) {
       var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
       el.addClass("come-in"); 
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, the animation doesn't work _at all_ in Chrome 33 on Mac.

Comment: I had to remove the effect, because I cannot find any solution for it. If and when you are willing to look into the issue, please post here, and I will make the changes so that you can look at it.

Comment: First, congratulation on your frontend design. It's very functional and pleasantly responsive. I would like to help you with your problem, but can't see a difference between Firefox and Chrome. What version of Chrome are you using? Care to add a screenshot of the expected and faulty experiments?

Comment: I had to make the website live, I am at home now, I will reupload the project as it was and then message here, Kad.

Comment: Hi, I think I can help you. However, the link to your site is broken. If you fix it, or make a jsfiddle, I can have a look.

Comment: @Kad, the changes have been made and I have reuploaded the css. You can see that on chrome, the divs with class 'unWcalls' leave a space at the bottom of the page after being animated, while in firefox, it works just fine.

Comment: @climbinghobo, please check the link now.

Comment: I still can't see a difference between Firefox and Chrome. What version of Chrome and Firefox are you using? Care to add a screenshot of the expected and faulty experiments?

Comment: Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m
Firefox 28.0

Chrome screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/71e6nefcj/
Firefox screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/jaszki2z9/

You can see, that chrome leaves a lot of empty space at the bottom.

Comment: If it can help someone to investigate for the issue; this works perfectly in Chrome beta channel (35.0.1916.27). We might want to look at major fixes inbetween versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you push the elements down with `translateY(2000px)` and then pull them straight back up with `translate(0px)`. Chrome therefore leaves a place for them at the bottom if that makes sense.
This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRNuW/) demonstrates the problem. (I didn't bother with all the vendor prefixes).

Instead, translate them down by default and pull them up on scroll, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/kRNuW/1/).

If it still prooves buggy, animate [margin-top](http://jsfiddle.net/kRNuW/2/) or [top on absolute position](http://jsfiddle.net/kRNuW/3/). Translate doesn't affect page layout as much and is better for performance, but that's part of your problem, right?

on a different note, a few issues I found:

1. The performance of your javascript here would be terrible. Every time the user scrolls up or down, even after all the animations are completed, you run this function to check the position. I'm sure you can refactor it a lot.
2. You have to also consider users with javascript disabled. Currently there's nothing presented on the page.
3. I think there's a min width set on your search box and it jots out of it's border on narrow screens.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! This method worked: jsfiddle.net/kRNuW/1

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code:

Change position relative to static and check may be it will work fine.

```
.sitewid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: static;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Good Luck....

Comment: I cannot remove the relative from this class, I tried the solution though, and it didn't remove the error.